# Are there formal names for these list/dict data structures

Tags: python

My code is working fine, but I made up a couple names for how I'm handling data in lists and dicts. I'm not sure if they are intuitive; they're just what popped in my head at the time.

Are there accepted names already in use? (If you have a made-up name that's better than mine, fine, but I'm really looking for generally accepted names if they exist.)

Specifically:

- datalist: a list of lists with headers in [0] followed by rows
- datamap: a list of dicts with name: value for every item

```py
headers = ['a', 'b', 'c']
rows = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]]
datalist = [['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
datamap = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}, {'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'c': 9}]
```

Comment: 1. Sounds good to me. 2. Even if it didn't, but it makes sense to you and the people who read your code, rule 1 applies.

Comment: You could probably call the datalist a table and everyone would know roughly what you were talking about. Neither is terribly specific, but using a new term implies additional (unspecified) semantics that made the older term unsuitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest thing to what you're describing is a [type hint](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/). It's an unambiguous way to specify the type of a data structure, as well as the types that the data structure holds. These type hints are ignored at runtime, but they help readers of your code understand what each data structure contains and can be used with libraries such as [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) to detect typing errors:

```py
from typing import Union, TypedDict

class DataEntry(TypedDict):
    a: int
    b: int
    c: int

DataMap = list[DataEntry]

headers: list[str] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
rows: list[list[int]] = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]]
datalist: list[Union[list[str], list[int]]] = [['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
datamap: DataMap = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}, {'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'c': 9}]
```

Comment: Interesting - that's new to me. Thanks